# Парсинг строк в php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
 if (preg_match_all("/!ban ........./i", "!ban 401662529", $arr)) {
                $k = var_dump($arr);
                var_export($k);
    }
```

Вот тут я получил массив ($arr[0]), что равно !ban 40166252,

Ожидаемый результат:

```
Array {
[0] => "!ban"
[1] => "40166252"
}
```

Полученный:

```
 Array {
    [0] => "!ban 40166252"
    }
```

Comment: `preg_match_all("/(!ban)\s+(\d+)/i", "!ban 401662529", $arr)`??

Comment: именованная группа не будет случаем уместнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте захватывающие подмаски, `(!ban)\s+(\d+)`:

```
if (preg_match_all("/(!ban)\s+(\d+)/i", "!ban 401662529", $arr, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    array_shift($arr[0]);
    print_r($arr[0]);
}
// = Array ( [0] => !ban  [1] => 401662529 )
```

См. [демо на PHP](https://3v4l.org/eXoBH).

**Подробности**

- `(!ban)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: строка `!ban`
- `\s+` - 1 и более пробельных символов
- `(\d+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №2: одна и более цифр.

Аргумент `PREG_SET_ORDER` группирует совпадения с захваченными подстроками, а `array_shift` удаляет полное совпадение.